# XMLHttpRequest multipart/form-data: Invalid boundary in multipart

Tags: javascript, python, xmlhttprequest

I am sending post data via XMLHttpRequest:

```
var xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open("POST", domain, true);
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","multipart/form-data");
var formData = new FormData();  
formData.append("data", data_json_string);
xmlHttp.send(formData);
```

In Python, I get an error if I try to get the POST (or FILES or anything) data:

```
MultiPartParserError: Invalid boundary in multipart: None
```

Can this never work?? Do I really need to create the form body as a single string where I loop through the parameters and place a boundary string before and after each one? And, if so, what should that look like? How do  I get it from my POST in Python?? Or is there an easier way. I'm looking around and not finding much on this.

btw, I am using "multipart/form-data" because my string data is really long and this is a faster way to send it. It has worked for me when I create a form and post it, targeting it to an iframe. But here I much prefer xmlHttp.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do not set the `Content-Type` header yourself. It will be properly set when `.send()`ing the data, including the proper generated boundary, which your manually generated header lacks.

The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/#the-send-method) clearly states that `.send(FormData)` will use multipart/form-data encoding.

> If data is a FormData
>
> Let the request entity body be the result of running the multipart/form-data encoding algorithm with data as form data set and with UTF-8 as the explicit character encoding.
>
> Let mime type be the concatenation of "multipart/form-data;", a U+0020 SPACE character, "boundary=", and the multipart/form-data boundary string generated by the multipart/form-data encoding algorithm.

Comment: I'm concerned that it is uri encoding it, thereby making it longer. This was an issue when sending it via a form, and setting the header made a big difference. But maybe that doesn't happen with xmlHttp?

Comment: Wow. I feel like this is uncommon knowledge. None of the major frontend JS frameworks even mention it--that I'm aware of.