# Overriding the contentType in backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views, backbone-events

Is it possible to override the `contentType="application/json"` to `contentType="multipart/form-data"` in backbone.js?

Any example for backbone file upload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do file uploads outside of an html form.  What folks usually do is have a hidden iframe which hosts a form to do the upload and then have their main html page communicate with that iframe so the form post doesn't disturb your otherwise seamless SPA UX.  This isn't a backbone-specific issue.

Comment: Can you please provide any example for file upload.

Comment: I recommend googling "js file upload".  Ignore the backbone element.  there are lots of articles and existing libraries that help deal with the cross-browser compatibility issues you'll hit.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, it is possible. I'm using it for file upload myself!

There are a couple of "gotchas."

1. You **cannot** manually set ContentType to 'multipart/form-data' for FormData() type uploads.
2. You **must** pass the data object into the options parameter when calling save().

This is due to the fact that there are attributes added to ContentType, such as `boundary`, that the browser must process and add. See [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18590630/xmlhttprequest-multipart-form-data-invalid-boundary-in-multipart) for details.

### Working Example:

```
var formData = new FormData($('#form-id')[0]);

model.save(null, {       // No need to set data parameter here.
    data: formData,      // Must put data here.
    processData: false,  // Don't let Backbone process the data.
    contentType: false,  // Don't let Backbone set content-type.
    success: function() {}
});
```

This will cause the browser to set the ContentType headers to the appropriate `'multipart/form-data; ....'` parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You pass the `contentType` option to the save method, and whatever data you want to put in there:

```
var model = new Backbone.Model();

model.save({
   contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
   data: /* Your data */
});
```

You can see that in the Backbone source [here](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/53f77901a4ea9c7cf75d3db93ddddf491998d90f/backbone.js#L1150).

Comment: want to override Specifically for file upload (multipart/form-data), other cases it should be application/json only.