# Using Superagent to submit a form via ajax containing an image value

Tags: javascript, ajax, pyramid, superagent

I've tried a few different methods and nothing seems to be submitting my icon file properly

```
request
  .post('/my/newapp')
  .type('multipart/form-data')
  .field('name', input.newAppName)
  .field('description', input.newAppDescription)
  .field('csrf', csrf.newApp)
  .attach('icon', this.refs.icon.value) // Doesn't save for some reason
  .end((err, res) => {...
```

For the submit above my request payload looks like:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarywygaaRkqk2Kr6zzJ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

afasfasfasf
------WebKitFormBoundarywygaaRkqk2Kr6zzJ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="description"


------WebKitFormBoundarywygaaRkqk2Kr6zzJ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="csrf"

16we7ncdfoyz5twnc1ilhg5pjgr6ze5s36153ffbf:aYCZkOQV6nxQq6mXWmCLOQ==
------WebKitFormBoundarywygaaRkqk2Kr6zzJ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="icon"


------WebKitFormBoundarywygaaRkqk2Kr6zzJ--
```

But I get a 502 on my pyramid application: `ValueError: Invalid boundary in multipart form: ''`.

I've also tried to use `FormData` to no avail.

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('name', input.newAppName);
formData.append('description', input.newAppDescription);
formData.append('csrf', csrf.newApp);
formData.append('icon', this.refs.icon.value);
request
  .post('/my/newapp')
  .type('form')
  .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
  .send(formData)
  .end((err, res) => {...
```

Any insight is much appreciated. If I do a normal non-ajax form post it works fine.

Comment: Does this fix your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18590630/xmlhttprequest-multipart-form-data-invalid-boundary-in-multipart ?

Comment: @limelights Thanks for your post. That didn't work either however. On the backend I am getting `FieldStorage('icon', u'myImage.jpg')` for the old form submit. And `C:\fakepath\myImage.jpg` for the new ajax form when using FormData. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I was using the wrong attribute when adding the icon to formData.

```
  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let {input, csrf, setErrorModal} = this.props;
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('name', input.newAppName);
    formData.append('description', input.newAppDescription);
    formData.append('csrf', csrf.newApp);
    formData.append('icon', this.refs.icon.files[0]);
    request
      .post('/my/newapp')
      .send(formData) // works now =-]
      .end((err, res) => {...
```

Comment: Could you please share how your rails controller action looks like? I'm doing this exactly, but I'm getting `ActionController::BadRequest (Invalid request parameters: invalid %-encoding` on rails side.

Comment: @Throoze I was using Python's Pyramid framework. I'm not familiar with how it would look like in Rails but if you search for AJAX image upload in Rails you should hopefully find something.