# raise MultiPartParserError in Django2.2

Tags: javascript, django, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to post the form data using 
'XMLHttprequest' to the django views and i'm getting **'A server error occurred.  Please 
contact the administrator.'** in the browser console, and 
 i'm getting following error

```
raise MultiPartParserError('Invalid boundary in multipart: %s' % boundary.decode())
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode'  in my terminal.
```

The following is my code snippet.

```
<html><head><tile></title>
 <body>
   <form>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" id="in" name="">
    <input type="button" id='' value="submit" onclick="myfunction()">
   </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function myfunction() {
      var emailId = document.getElementById('in').value;
      var csrfToken = getCookie("csrftoken");
      var myform = new FormData();
      myform.append("email", emailId);
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.open("POST", '{% url "log" %}', true);
      xhttp.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', csrfToken );
      xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;charset=utf-8");
      xhttp.send(myform);
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          console.log(this.responseText)
        }
     };
  }
</script>
<body>
</html>
```

This is my urls.py file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from zifapp import views

urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('login/', views.login),
   path('log', views.xmlhttprequest, name='log'),

]
```

and this is my views.py file

```
 from django.http import JsonResponse

 def xmlhttprequest(request):
    print(request.POST.get('email', False))
    return JsonResponse({'status':True}, safe=False)
```

Comment: it is a backend related issue, add some relevant code i.e. views, forms and error traceback.

Comment: okay, @nalin Dobhal -  I will share my backend code..

Comment: @nalin Dobhal - no issues in my backend code, and url 'log' is working fine.

Comment: I tried to replicate the issue, and looks like the content-type of header is no correct. i found this similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18590706)